# Проверка наличия переменной окружения

Tags: qt, qmake

Как проверить наличие переменной окружения при сборке проекта из qmake 
Переменная окружения может быть установлена, а может и нет.
в qmake необходимо провести анализ наличия и соответственно по разному собрать проект
Сборка проекта ведется под Windows и под Linux
Перепробовал так, даже если переменная окружения VAR_ENV не объявлена все равно говорит что не пусто (при этом выводит пустую строку):

```
VAR=$$(VAR_ENV)
!isEmpty (VAR) {
 message($$VAR)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не очень наверное красиво,  но работает. 
В pro или pri файл.

```
linux-g++-64 {
  !system ("./test.sh") {
    VAR = 0
    # действие если объявления нет
  } 
  else {
    VAR = $$(VAR_ENV)
    # действие если объявление есть
  }
}
win32 {
  !system(test.bat) {
    VAR = 0
    # действие если объявления нет
  }
  else {
    VAR = $$(VAR_ENV)
    # действие если объявление есть
  }
}
```

И два скрипта для Windows и Linux. 
Файл test.bat.

```
@echo off
set VAR_ENV%1 | findstr "." 
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (exit 9) else (exit 0)
```

Файл test.sh.

```
if [ -z ${VAR_ENV+x} ]; then 
  exit 9;
else
  exit 0;
fi
```